# onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState function not working

Tags: android

My app is about a textview that displays a background color, and the user needs to name that color correctly. When the user rotates the phone, I want the app to maintain the same color. So I used the onSaveInstaceState function and onRestoreInstanceState function. Unfortunately, the color changes when the user rotates the phone. I'm not sure what's wrong with my code

```
package com.example.lab2_group5;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PersistableBundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView question_TextView;
    private EditText answer_EditText;
    private Button submit_Button;
    private Button newGame_Button;

    //For intent that goes to MainActivity2
    public final static String KEY_COLOR_NAME = "com.example.lab2_group5.COLOR_NAME";
    public final static String KEY_STATUS = "com.example.lab2_group5.STATUS";

    String colorName = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        question_TextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.question_TextView);
        answer_EditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.answer_EditText);
        submit_Button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.submit_Button);
        newGame_Button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.newGame_Button);

        generateRandomColors();

        //What happens when the user click the SUBMIT button
        submit_Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //store the user input to the string variable called "answerByUser" and then convert it to uppercase for case sensitivity
                String answerByUser = answer_EditText.getText().toString();
                answerByUser = answerByUser.toUpperCase(); //Convert to uppercase

                //Check for empty input
                if(answerByUser.matches("")){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please enter your answer!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                //If no empty input
                else{
                    //Check if the user entered the correct color. Then, create an intent to send to the second activity
                    if(answerByUser.matches(colorName)){
                        newGame_Button.setEnabled(true);
                        createIntent(1, colorName);
                    }
                    else{
                        newGame_Button.setEnabled(true);
                        createIntent(-1, colorName);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        //What happens when the user click the NEW GAME button
        newGame_Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                generateRandomColors();
                newGame_Button.setEnabled(false);
            }
        });



    }

    private void generateRandomColors(){
        //Generate a random number between 0-9
        Random r = new Random();
        int randomNumber_Color = r.nextInt(10 - 0) + 0;

        //Assign the background color to the text view based on the random number. Also store the color name in a string variable
        switch (randomNumber_Color){
            case 0:
                question_TextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                colorName = "BLUE";
                break;
            case 1:
                question_TextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                colorName = "RED";
                break;
            case 2:
                question_TextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                colorName = "GREEN";
                break;
            case 3:
                question_TextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
                colorName = "CYAN";
                break;
            case 4:
                question_TextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                colorName = "BLACK";
                break;
            case 5:
                question_TextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
                colorName = "YELLOW";
                break;
            case 6:
                question_TextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(235, 122, 52)); //Orange
                colorName = "ORANGE";
                break;
            case 7:
                question_TextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                colorName = "GRAY";
                break;
            case 8:
                question_TextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(235, 52, 180)); //Pink
                colorName = "PINK";
                break;
            case 9:
                question_TextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(131, 52, 235)); //Purple
                colorName = "PURPLE";
                break;
        }
    }

    private void createIntent(int status, String colorName){
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity2.class);
        intent.putExtra(KEY_STATUS, status);
        intent.putExtra(KEY_COLOR_NAME, colorName);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putString("Question_TextViewColor", colorName);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        if(savedInstanceState != null){
            String nameOfColor = savedInstanceState.getString("Question_TextViewColor");

            switch("nameOfColor"){
                case "BLUE":
                    question_TextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                    break;
                case "RED":
                    question_TextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                    break;
                case "GREEN":
                    question_TextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                    break;
                case "CYAN":
                    question_TextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
                    break;
                case "BLACK":
                    question_TextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                    break;
                case "YELLOW":
                    question_TextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
                    break;
                case "ORANGE":
                    question_TextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(235, 122, 52)); //Orange
                    break;
                case "GRAY":
                    question_TextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                    break;
                case "PINK":
                    question_TextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(235, 52, 180)); //Pink
                    break;
                case "PURPLE":
                    question_TextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(131, 52, 235)); //Purple
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: inside onrestore: `switch("nameOfColor")` - you accidentally put variable name into quotes. And you probably want to assign it directly to `colorName` instead of using variable so it gets saved if you rotate the phone again.

Comment: @Pawel, Thanks for pointing out about the variable name into quotes. Sorry, I still don't understand what you mean by "assign it directly to `colorName` instead of using variable so it gets saved if you rotate the phone again."